# Magento - split options of container1 and container2

Tags: html, magento, magento-1.7, php

In the default layout the options and add-to-cart-button are called by

```
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
```

I would like to split the configurable options from the add-to-cart and quantity field to show them on a different position in my layout. Any ideas or ready to use workarounds?

Comment: Are you got? i too need 'add-to-cart' link for manual.

Comment: As this old topic gets a lot of views I would like to share my workaround for this problem.  
I looked out for the content inside `container1` and rendered it directly in the view-Template or call the content with `getChildHtml` for the product options this would be `$this->getChildHtml('product_options_wrapper')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can split it very easy (but I spent a lot of time to find it :) ) - if you look to the **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php** to PHPDoc of **public function getChildChildHtml**, you will see that the second parameter determined child block name. So, you can call first before the price block render

```
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', 'product.info.options.wrapper', true, true) ?>
```

and after price block rendered, call

```
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', 'product.info.options.wrapper.bottom', true, true) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While your final solution will depend on where these blocks need to be moved/inserted in your layout, you can definitely split the “Add to Cart” `product.info.options.wrapper.bottom` out from configurable options `product.info.container1` or `product.info.container2` like this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.container1">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.container2">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

The easiest way to then show the “Add to Cart” button separately is to comment out the conditional in `catalog/product/view.phtml` which allows the `product.info.addtocart` block to be shown whether the product has options or not:

```
<?php if (!$this->hasOptions()): // Remove this condition ?>
    <div class="add-to-box">
        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>

            ...

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    ...

<?php endif; ?>
```

Hopefully that helps you understand the structure of these blocks. Additional resources that may be helpful:

- [What is container1 and container2 in product view page in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/9271/20131)
- [How to move breadcrumb Block purely via local.xml?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/3637/20131)